# How to pass parameters that are not string to the exception in C#?

Tags: c#, api, exception, httpresponse

I was working on want to return response body in the API if API return 400 Bad Request. Meaning to say is when my API return 400 Bad Request, it comes along with a response body not only status code.

In my custom exception class, I have a method like this:

```
public Errors CreateErrorResponseBody(string id, string code)
{
   return new Errors
   {
      Id = id,
      Code = code
   }
}
```

The constructor in my custom exception class looks like this:

```
public CustomException(string message) : base(message){}
```

In my method that throws exception, I have like this:

```
string id = "AAA";
string code = "123";
...
catch(Exception ex)
{
   if (ex is DeviceManagementServiceException e)
   {
      e.CreateErrorResponseBody(id, code);
      throw new CustomException();
   }
}
```

In my controller, I have my exception handling method like this:

```
private IActionResult HandleException(CustomException exception)
{
   return Json(errorResponseBody)
}
```

How can I get the `errorResponseBody` to above method to return?
The exception constructor only allows passing string.

Is there a way that I can throw my exception along with the `errorResponseBody` that I created, then eventually let the controller return that response body?

Or is there any other way that I can return response body to my API response?

Thanks!

Comment: There usually not body when you get a http error.  Only when you get a good response 200 OK.  You can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to see what data is in the body, but I do not think there will be any body data.

Comment: Yeah however I want my API to return a body when someone else calls it and it's an error.

Comment: Do you want to return data when a hacker attempts to access the database and the credentials fail?  Under what conditions do you want a body to contain data?  You could be dealing with security issues.  Even if your API returns data most clients ignore the data when response is not 200 OK.

Comment: Define a constructor for your CustomException that accepts something other than string, which gets stored in some property?